# Ansible: print list of packages, removed by apt autoremove

Tags: ansible

I use apt autoremove in my playbook:

```
- name: remove autoinstalled crap
  apt:
    autoremove: yes
```

I would like to see list of removed packages in the output of `ansible-playbook`. Is it possible?

Answer (score 4):

There is no standard procedure. The list of the removed packages must be created. For example, register the returned data

```yaml
    - name: remove autoinstalled crap
      apt:
        autoremove: yes
      register: result
```

[select](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/master/templates/#select) lines with removed packages and *map* [regex_replace](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#searching-strings-with-regular-expressions) second groups which should be the names of the removed packages

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        pkg_removed: "{{ result.stdout_lines|
                         select('regex', '^Removing (.*)$')|
                         map('regex_replace', '^(.*?) (.*?) (.*)$', '\\2')|
                         list }}"
    - debug:
        var: pkg_removed
```

give (after the recent update of Ubuntu 20.04)

```yaml
  pkg_removed:
  - linux-headers-5.4.0-29-generic
  - linux-headers-5.4.0-29
  - linux-headers-5.4.0-31-generic
  - linux-headers-5.4.0-31
  - linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-29-generic
  - linux-image-5.4.0-29-generic
  - linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-31-generic
  - linux-image-5.4.0-31-generic
  - linux-modules-5.4.0-29-generic
  - linux-modules-5.4.0-31-generic
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. Only one thing: I've added `when: result.changed` to both tasks (otherwise it fails if no packages were deleted).

BTW, it is noisily a bit. Unfortunately, it seems like there is no way to suppress `set_fact` output.

Comment: Try other [callback plugin](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/callback.html#plugin-list).